# minidlna Ubuntu 13.10 server: start on boot

Tags: server, 13.10, minidlna

I'm trying to build a server with minidlna installed. Installation worked fine, but having it run on startup is more problematic. I added minidlna to my rc.local, and now on boot I get log messages stating:

> minidlna.c:132: error: bind(http): Address already in use
>   minidlna.c:1004: fatal: Failed to open socket for HTTP. EXITING

I have tried setting the bind device (eth0), and changing the port, which is now 8300 instead of 8200. All in vain. And, even more unsettling: when I start minidlna manually from the terminal, it runs just fine. This makes me suspect the config is not the problem; I just cannot figure out what is. Could somebody give me a suggestion?

Thanks a million!

Ruud

Answer (score 0):

Although networking is started before rc.local runs, networking may not yet be ready (e.g. waiting for an IP address from DHCP). An easy work around may be adding

```
sleep 2m
```

before the actual command starting minidlna. Of course you can adjust the time "2m" to an amount suitable for your setup.